# Create N-element constexpr array in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, array-initialization

Hello i'm learning C++11, I'm wondering how to make a constexpr 0 to n array, for example:

```
n = 5;

int array[] = {0 ... n};
```

so array may be `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Comment: [Here's a recent similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19016099/420683) using `std::array`s.

Comment: We're at C++17 now. So, @abyx 's answer is now the best answer, because it can no longer be considered to be dependent on "compiler extensions".

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In C++14 it can be easily done with a `constexpr` constructor and a loop:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
struct A {
    constexpr A() : arr() {
        for (auto i = 0; i != N; ++i)
            arr[i] = i; 
    }
    int arr[N];
};

int main() {
    constexpr auto a = A<4>();
    for (auto x : a.arr)
        std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Comment: this is concise. Why is `: arr()` necessary?

Comment: @IceFire probably because you cannot have uninitialized fields in `constexpr` function (which is a constructor here). Just a guess.

Comment: How could you pass a function to A that would be applied to all array elements? When using `template <int N, class Function> ... constexpr A(Function f) : arr() {...` I can't figure out how to instantiate the struct.

Comment: Note: doesn't work with Visual Studio 15, might be supported in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I cant get this to compile. I am also using Visual Studio 15. Can someone confirm that it is valid in 2017+?

Comment: This works fine for me with C++17 in Visual Studio 2019. Regarding a short experiment on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WdzTj3a6z), the example also compiles with the oldest msvc toolchain 19.14 available there, which seems to be shipped with Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 58):

Unlike those answers in the comments to your question, you can do this without compiler extensions.

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N, int... Rest>
struct Array_impl {
    static constexpr auto& value = Array_impl<N - 1, N, Rest...>::value;
};

template<int... Rest>
struct Array_impl<0, Rest...> {
    static constexpr int value[] = { 0, Rest... };
};

template<int... Rest>
constexpr int Array_impl<0, Rest...>::value[];

template<int N>
struct Array {
    static_assert(N >= 0, "N must be at least 0");

    static constexpr auto& value = Array_impl<N>::value;

    Array() = delete;
    Array(const Array&) = delete;
    Array(Array&&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Array<4>::value[3]; // prints 3
}
```

Comment: @Kal nice, but "only" works for `int` or other types that can appear as non-type template parameters (so not for e.g. `double`). See my answer for the general solution.

Comment: Nice. But I think I would hide the recursive variadic template behind a non-variadic public interface, to avoid confusion if somebody tries `Array<9,3,5>`.

Answer (score 40):

Based on @Xeo's [excellent idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13315884/819272), here is an approach that lets you fill an array of

- `constexpr std::array<T, N> a = { fun(0), fun(1), ..., fun(N-1) };`
- where `T` is any literal type (not just `int` or other valid non-type template parameter types), but also `double`, or `std::complex` (from C++14 onward)
- where `fun()` is any `constexpr` function
- which is supported by `std::make_integer_sequence` from C++14 onward, but easily implemented today with both g++ and Clang (see Live Example at the end of the answer)
- I use @JonathanWakely 's [implementation at GitHub](https://gitorious.org/redistd/integer_seq/raw/fdce85d18df4ea99240524c626d5452a0f7c3faf:integer_seq.h) (Boost License)

Here is the code

```
template<class Function, std::size_t... Indices>
constexpr auto make_array_helper(Function f, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) 
-> std::array<typename std::result_of<Function(std::size_t)>::type, sizeof...(Indices)> 
{
    return {{ f(Indices)... }};
}

template<int N, class Function>
constexpr auto make_array(Function f)
-> std::array<typename std::result_of<Function(std::size_t)>::type, N> 
{
    return make_array_helper(f, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});    
}

constexpr double fun(double x) { return x * x; }

int main() 
{
    constexpr auto N = 10;
    constexpr auto a = make_array<N>(fun);

    std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ", ")); 
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/663dee82db2aef0a)

Comment: `where auto is any literal type` Isn't it a `std::array` of literal types, in `auto a = make_array<N>(fun);`, equivalent to `auto a = std::array<decltype(fun(0)), N>{fun(0), fun(1), ..};`? Also, the example `constexpr auto a = {1,2};` deduces `a` to be a `std::initializer_list`, which isn't yet required to be a literal type (-> no `constexpr`). (I know it's rather pedantic, but I was confused at first glance.)

Answer (score 6):

Use  C++14 integral_sequence, or its invariant index_sequence

```
#include <iostream>

template< int ... I > struct index_sequence{ 

    using type = index_sequence;
    using value_type = int;

    static constexpr std::size_t size()noexcept{ return sizeof...(I); }
};

// making index_sequence
template< class I1, class I2> struct concat;

template< int ...I, int ...J> 
struct concat< index_sequence<I...>, index_sequence<J...> > 
        :  index_sequence< I ... , ( J + sizeof...(I) )... > {};

template< int N > struct make_index_sequence_impl;

template< int N > 
using make_index_sequence = typename make_index_sequence_impl<N>::type;

template< > struct make_index_sequence_impl<0> : index_sequence<>{};
template< > struct make_index_sequence_impl<1> : index_sequence<0>{};

template< int N > struct make_index_sequence_impl 
     : concat< make_index_sequence<N/2>, make_index_sequence<N - N/2> > {};



// now, we can build our structure.   
template < class IS > struct mystruct_base;

template< int ... I >
struct mystruct_base< index_sequence< I ... > >
{

   static constexpr int array[]{I ... };
};

template< int ... I >
constexpr int mystruct_base< index_sequence<I...> >::array[] ;

template< int N > struct mystruct 
   : mystruct_base< make_index_sequence<N > > 
{};

int main()
{
    mystruct<20> ms;

    //print
    for(auto e : ms.array)
    {
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

output: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

---

UPDATE: 
    You may use std::array:

```
template< int ... I >
static constexpr std::array< int, sizeof...(I) >  build_array( index_sequence<I...> ) noexcept 
{ 
   return std::array<int, sizeof...(I) > { I... };
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 20> ma = build_array( make_index_sequence<20>{} );

    for(auto e : ma) std::cout << e << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Clang + libc++ tip of tree support this. Pass `-std=c++1y`.

Comment: I use Clang 3.3  and GCC 4.8.1   with -std=c++11 options.

Answer (score 2):

For std::array in C++17,
constexpr function are also accepted
Note that the var 'arr' must be **initialized** by constexpr required.
(initialize: same meaning with answer of @abyx)

```cpp
#include <array>
constexpr std::array<int, 3> get_array()
{
    std::array<int, 3> arr{0};
    arr[0] = 9;
    return arr;
}
static_assert(get_array().size() == 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

With C++17 this can be done easily as `std::array::begin` is marked `constexpr`.

```
template<std::size_t N> std::array<int, N + 1> constexpr make_array()
{
    std::array<int, N + 1> tempArray{};
    int count = 0;
    for(int &elem:tempArray)
    {
        elem = count++;
    }
    return tempArray;
}
int main()
{
    
    //-------------------------------vv------>pass the size here 
    constexpr auto arr  = make_array<5>();
   
    //lets confirm if all objects have the expected value 
    for(const auto &elem: arr)
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl; //prints 1 2 3 4 5 with newline in between
    }
    
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qKr4Y176G)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<int... N>
struct expand;

template<int... N>
struct expand<0, N...>
{
    constexpr static std::array<int, sizeof...(N) + 1> values = {{ 0, N... }};
};

template<int L, int... N> struct expand<L, N...> : expand<L-1, L, N...> {};

template<int... N>
constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(N) + 1> expand<0, N...>::values;

int main()
{
    std::cout << expand<100>::values[9];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using boost preprocessor, it's very simple:

```
 #include <cstdio>
 #include <cstddef>

 #include <boost/preprocessor/repeat.hpp>
 #include <boost/preprocessor/comma_if.hpp>

 #define IDENTITY(z,n,dummy)   BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(n) n

 #define INITIALIZER_n(n)   { BOOST_PP_REPEAT(n,IDENTITY,~)  }

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
     int array[] = INITIALIZER_n(25);

     for(std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); ++i)
        printf("%d ",array[i]);

     return 0;
 }
```

OUTPUT:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

Comment: I think you could also use one of the `ENUM` macros, e.g. `BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(25, BOOST_PP_EMPTY())`, instead of the `REPEAT`+`COMMA_IF`

Answer (score -6):

Consider [`boost::mpl::range_c<int, 0, N>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/range-c.html) instead.