# Initialize a constexpr array as sum of other two constexpr arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initialization, initializer-list

Given two `constexpr` arrays (`type[N]` or `std::array<type, N>`)

```
constexpr int A[5] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
constexpr int B[5] { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
```

is it possible to initialize a new `constexpr` array performing an element-wise operation (or `constexpr` function)?

For example, can this code

```
constexpr int sum(int i) { return A[i] + B[i]; }
constexpr int S[5] { sum(0), sum(1), sum(2), sum(3), sum(4) };
```

be rewritten more conveniently in a form that calls `sum(i)` for every element in `S`?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19023500/923854.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Similar things have been done many times already, but here's a solution for *this* particular compile-time operation on arrays ;)

```
template<int... Is>
struct seq {};
template<int I, int... Is>
struct gen_seq : gen_seq<I-1, I-1, Is...> {};
template<int... Is>
struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...> {};

#include <array>

template<class T, int N, int... Is>
constexpr std::array<T, N> sum(T const (&lhs)[N], T const (&rhs)[N], seq<Is...>)
{
    return {{lhs[Is]+rhs[Is]...}};
}

template<class T, int N>
constexpr auto sum(T const (&lhs)[N], T const (&rhs)[N])
-> decltype( sum(lhs, rhs, gen_seq<N>{}) )
{
    return sum(lhs, rhs, gen_seq<N>{});
}

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    constexpr int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    constexpr int b[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    constexpr auto c = sum(a,b);

    for(auto e : c) std::cout << e << ", ";
}
```

N.B. `std::array::operator[]` is *not* `constexpr` in C++11, therefore I've used raw arrays as input.

---

For arbitrary binary functions:

```
template<class T, int N, class F, int... Is>
constexpr auto transform(T const (&lhs)[N], T const (&rhs)[N], F f,
                         seq<Is...>)
-> std::array<decltype( f(lhs[0], rhs[0]) ), N>
{
    return {{ f(lhs[Is], rhs[Is])... }};
}

template<class T, int N, class F>
constexpr auto transform(T const (&lhs)[N], T const (&rhs)[N], F f)
-> decltype( transform(lhs, rhs, f, gen_seq<N>{}) )
{
    return transform(lhs, rhs, f, gen_seq<N>{});
}

constexpr int sum(int l, int r) { return l+r; }
// ...
constexpr auto c = transform(a,b,sum);
```

---

For arbitrary n-ary functions and arbitrary array-like types:

```
template<class F, class... Args>
constexpr auto index_invoke(F f, int i, Args&&... args)
-> decltype( f(args[i]...) )
{
    return f(args[i]...);
}

template<class F, int... Is, class... Args>
constexpr auto transform_impl(F f, seq<Is...>, Args&&... args)
-> std::array<decltype( f(args[0]...) ), sizeof...(Is)>
{
    return {{ index_invoke(f, Is, std::forward<Args>(args)...)... }};
}

template <class T, class...>
struct get_extent_helper
: std::integral_constant<int,
                         std::extent<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>{}>
{};

template<class F, class... Args>
constexpr auto transform(F f, Args&&... args)
-> decltype( transform_impl(f, gen_seq< get_extent_helper<Args...>{} >{},
                            std::forward<Args>(args)...) )
{
    using N = get_extent_helper<Args...>;
    return transform_impl(f, gen_seq<N{}>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

More lightweight with an alias-template:

```
template <class T, class...>
using get_extent_helper =
  std::integral_constant<int,
                         std::extent<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>{}>;
```

But this is buggy under g++4.8.1

Comment: Awesome! I learned a bunch from this answer, thanks very much!

Comment: nitpick: `std::get` [is constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/get) for `std::array`s

Comment: @TomKnapen "The overloads are marked as constexpr since C++14." :(

Comment: For anyone worried about the performance of the above, I did extensive tests of compiling his transform "arbitrary binary" using lambda's for F vs a simple loop and in all cases, using optimized settings, the code created on x86 was similar if not exactly the same.  In large arrays the compiler made a looping function and short ones it just unrolled both.