# How to automatically fill a std::array base on sizeof a variadic template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, c++14

In this simplified code :

```
template <int... vars>
struct Compile_Time_Array_Indexes
{
    static std::array < int, sizeof...(vars)> indexes;//automatically fill it base on sizeof...(vars)
};
template <int ... vars>
struct Compile_Time_Array :public Compile_Time_Array_Indexes<vars...>
{
};
```

I want to automatically fill `indexes` base on the `vars...` size .

**Example :**

```
Compile_Time_Array <1,3,5,2> arr1;//indexes --> [0,1,2,3]
Compile_Time_Array <8,5> arr2;   // indexes --> [0,1]
```

Any idea ?

Comment: C++14 brought [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) (though if these are indices, you might consider using `std::size_t`, which has a nice premade `std::index_sequence` for it).

Comment: something like [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19023500/819272)? (also works without `constexpr` IIRC)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following definition apparently works with GCC-4.9 and Clang-3.5:

```
template <typename Type, Type ...Indices>
auto make_index_array(std::integer_sequence<Type, Indices...>)
    -> std::array<Type, sizeof...(Indices)>
{
    return std::array<Type, sizeof...(Indices)>{Indices...};
}

template <int... vars>
std::array<int, sizeof...(vars)> 
Compile_Time_Array_Indexes<vars...>::indexes
    = make_index_array<int>(std::make_integer_sequence<int, sizeof...(vars)>{});
```

Comment: This doesn't fill the array with indices, though. Rather, it fills array with the same numbers as in the parameter pack.

Comment: @chris: You are right. I didn't see that in the OP's question. I have fixed the answer.

Comment: @OP, Just so you know, there are many implementations of such an integer sequence for C++11 such that you could grab one and use it with this code.

Comment: @nosid I'm trying to compile it in vs 2013 I add an implementation of make_integer_sequence  but this line give me an error `Compile_Time_Array_Indexes<vars...>::indexes` :  `missing ';' before '<'`

Comment: @xyz Here, I used the standard "indecies trick" to make this work in C++11: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0113a31abe51b68f.  It _ought_ to work in VS2013.

Comment: @Casey tnx . you should make it an answer .

Comment: @MooingDuck visual studio 2013 does not support constexpr :(