# how to store a const array in executable?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, constexpr

I want to store a calculated const array such that `a[i] = i*i -3;`

Here is what I was thinking, but I'm not sure:

```
constexpr int fun(int x) {
  return x * x - 3;
}

template<int N>
struct A {
  constexpr A() : array() {
    for (auto i = 0; i != N; ++i) array[i] = fun(i); 
  }
  int array[N];
};

const A<4> array1{};
const int array2[] = {-3, -2, 1, 6};
```

I think `array1` is initialized, not stored in the executable like `array2`.

Is it possible to do this without using a macro?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create N-element constexpr array in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019252/create-n-element-constexpr-array-in-c11) particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19023500/2757035), which I have made great use of.

Comment: Both global variables can be stored in the executable. For an elf binary, for example, they will be located in the `.rodata` section. What you might experience is the compiler removing the variable because it does not detect any reference to it. If you want to make sure it is visible from the outside regardless of being used or not, declare your variable as `extern`: see https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/E-M9r5

Comment: Maybe you would have better luck initializing `array` in the initializer list rather than the constructor body.

Comment: @underscore_d: is what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do this without using a macro?

What about a delegating constructor?

```
template<int N>
struct A {

  template <int ... Is>
  constexpr A(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>)
     : array{ fun(Is)... }
   { }

  constexpr A() : A{std::make_integer_sequence<int, N>{}}
   { }

  int array[N];
};
```