# How to Create constexpr Array Where Elements Depend on the Array’s Size?

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

How can I create a `constexpr` array, where the array elements are calculated and depend on the size of the array? Look at the example below in the initializer list to see what I mean.

```cpp
template <short NUM_TRIANGLES>
constexpr auto circle() {
    constexpr float angle = (M_PI / 2.0f) / NUM_TRIANGLES;
    constexpr std::array<float, NUM_TRIANGLES> angles{angle, 2 * angle, 3 * angle, ... /* LOOK HERE */};

    /// ...
}
```

Comment: Did you try looking this up? There are many duplicates explaining this.

Comment: @user12002570 yes, but I can't formulate my question accurately enough to find an example.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74908034/12002570) that should solve your problem and be trivial to modify.