# Efficiently convert two Integers x and y into the float x.y

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, decimal

Given two integers X and Y, whats the most efficient way of converting them into X.Y float value in C++?

E.g.

```
 X = 3, Y = 1415 -> 3.1415

 X = 2, Y = 12   -> 2.12
```

Comment: That can probably be done but I hope you already know that it's really *odd*, for example you can't represent `1.01` that way because it would have `x = 1, y = 1` but that actually means `1.1` already. Meanwhile `x = 1, y = 10` *also* means `1.1`

Comment: @harold good catch with 1.1 = 1.10, still would like to know how its done.

Comment: What do you mean by float and integer? is it 4 byte float? ist it 4 byte integer? signed or unsigned? What means efficient?

Comment: With the `log `function you can find how many digits a number has. Then divide by 10 expont this digits-number

Comment: What are you planning to do with the float?

Comment: @TarekDakhran unsigned values, int value would be 2-bytes max each. Floating value could be a double

Comment: Why do you need this kind of conversion? Serialize? Do you need the double->2 ints conversion? What about representing `1.01`?

Comment: You should tell whether you want the **NEAREST** float or an approximation to a few bits (a few ulp)

Comment: Most of the answers are subject to double rounding problems. For example, `2.5001 != (2.0 + 0.5001)` that's why specifying if answer has to be correctly rounded or not will make a difference on *efficiency*

Comment: @tunafish24 "_whats the most efficient way_" - seems to be a question without a definite answer - or what kind of answer would make you accept it?

Answer (score 7):

Here are some cocktail-napkin benchmark results, on my machine, for all solutions converting two `int`s to a `float`, as of the time of writing.

Caveat: I've now added a solution of my own, which seems to do well, and am therefore biased! Please double-check my results.

| Test | Iterations | ns / iteration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| @aliberro's conversion v2 | 79,113,375 | 13 |
| @3Dave's conversion | 84,091,005 | 12 |
| @einpoklum's conversion | 1,966,008,981 | 0 |
| @Ripi2's conversion | 47,374,058 | 21 |
| @TarekDakhran's conversion | 1,960,763,847 | 0 |

- CPU: Quad Core Intel Core i5-7600K speed/min/max: 4000/800/4200 MHz
- Devuan GNU/Linux 3
- Kernel: 5.2.0-3-amd64 x86_64
- GCC 9.2.1, with flags: `-O3 -march=native -mtune=native`

[Benchmark code](https://gist.github.com/eyalroz/ebea248b41f0b32d4e92109c4e9233e8) (Github Gist).

Comment: I could not find the word "fast" in the question. My interpretation of the word "efficient" is different. And the execution speed has no meaning in this more academic question

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @einpoklum, I updated my answer, please reevaluate.

Comment: @3Dave: Now even more interesting... :-P

Comment: @einpoklum Damn lookup tables getcha every time. Nice solution, though. :)

Comment: @einpoklum I did earlier. :)

Comment: @einpoklum look at my post, version 2 and benchmark it if you can, I think this will do much better than the first

Comment: @einpoklum So, what are the numbers for my solution with `uint32_t`? I see the table update, but no numbers there

Comment: @TarekDakhran: Going to sleep now. Also, please implement a conversion of two `int`s into a `float` so we can compare everything. Alternatively - you can convert everyone else's answers to take `uint32_t`s and return `double`s and run that benchmark.

Comment: I compared your implementation to mine myself. Here are the results http://quick-bench.com/xao6aY9m0YHMpr55J1oXjaspUgM . Good night. If we take your table lookup for pow_10 and my digits_10 together, this will give fastest possible  solution.

Comment: @TarekDakhran: No more UB, but - our numbers both look a bit suspicious, as though everything is being optimized away.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer in its own right - it's a meta-answer about other answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26022995).

Comment: @WaiHaLee: It is a partial answer, in the sense of being important to understand what's efficient and what's not. Also, there are multiple such questions, AFAICR, which have answers benchmarking other answers. Finally, viewers find this useful.

Answer (score 6):

```
float sum = x + y / pow(10,floor(log10(y)+1));
```

`log10` returns log (base 10) of its argument. For 1234, that'll be 3 point something.

Breaking this down:

```
log10(1234) = 3.091315159697223
floor(log10(1234)+1) = 4
pow(10,4) = 10000.0
3 + 1234 / 10000.0 = 3.1234.
```

But, as @einpoklum pointed out, `log(0)` is `NaN`, so you have to check for that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

float foo(int x, unsigned int y)
{
    if (0==y)
        return x;

    float den = pow(10,-1 * floor(log10(y)+1));
    return x + y * den; 
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> tests
    {
     {3,1234},
     {1,1000},
     {2,12},
     {0,0},
     {9,1}
    };

    for(auto& test: tests)
    {
        cout << "Test: " << test[0] << "," << test[1] << ": " << foo(test[0],test[1]) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

See runnable version at: 
https://onlinegdb.com/rkaYiDcPI

With test output:

> Test: 3,1234: 3.1234
>   Test: 1,1000: 1.1
>   Test: 2,12: 2.12
>   Test: 0,0: 0
>   Test: 9,1: 9.1

*Edit*

Small modification to remove division operation.

Comment: What about y == 0?

Comment: @einpoklum Good call. fixed.

Comment: Errr...1234 / 1000 != 0.1234

Comment: @Ripi2 I posted too quickly. Silly off-by-1 and an edge case. I should go back to bed and start the day over.

Comment: Don't post fast & loose, or else fails arise. E.g. what if `y=1000`? Then `log10y(y)+1` doesn't work

Comment: I think log floor and pow are very expensive

Comment: @kvantour Yes, but they are *a lot* cheaper than string operations.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>(reworked solution)</sub>

Initially, my thoughts were improving on the performance of power-of-10 and division-by-power-of-10 by writing specialized versions of these functions, for integers. Then there was @TarekDakhran's comment about doing the same for counting the number of digits. And then I realized: That's essentially doing the same thing twice... so let's just integrate everything. This will, specifically, allow us to completely avoid any divisions or inversions at runtime:

```
inline float convert(int x, int y) {
    float fy (y);
    if (y == 0)  { return float(x); }
    if (y >= 1e9) { return float(x + fy * 1e-10f); }
    if (y >= 1e8) { return float(x + fy * 1e-9f);  }
    if (y >= 1e7) { return float(x + fy * 1e-8f);  }
    if (y >= 1e6) { return float(x + fy * 1e-7f);  }
    if (y >= 1e5) { return float(x + fy * 1e-6f);  }
    if (y >= 1e4) { return float(x + fy * 1e-5f);  }
    if (y >= 1e3) { return float(x + fy * 1e-4f);  }
    if (y >= 1e2) { return float(x + fy * 1e-3f);  }
    if (y >= 1e1) { return float(x + fy * 1e-2f);  }
                    return float(x + fy * 1e-1f); 
}
```

Additional notes:

- This will work for `y == 0`; but - not for negative x or y values. Adapting it for negative value is pretty easy and not very expensive though.
- Not sure if this is absolutely optimal. Perhaps a binary-search for the number of digits of y would work better?
- A loop would make the code look nicer; but the compiler would need to unroll it. Would it unroll the loop and compute all those floats beforehand? I'm not sure.

Comment: For `(0, 9)`, this returns 0.900000035762786865234375 but 0.89999997615814208984375 is a closer representable value to .9 (with IEEE-754 binary32). For `(0, 10)` this returns 1 but should return a value near .10.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: See edit. About the non-optimality - I believe that is a reasonable price to pay for efficiency; but - do you have a concrete suggestion? Perhaps checking whether adding or subtracting epsilon (depending on the direction of error) brings us closer?

Comment: `(x*p + y)/p`, where `p` is a `float` with the selected power of 10, will produce the best answer as long as `x*p+y` is within the range where the floating-point format represents all integers (up to 2^24 for IEEE-754 binary32), but then you have an unwanted division.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: 1. What about `(x *(1/p) + y) * (1/p)`? 2. We can't assume `x*p+y` is within that range. In fact, for uniformly-sampled integers (albeit an unlikely distribution in practice), this will rarely be the case.

Comment: I presume you mean `(x*p + y) * (1/p)`, not `x *(1/p) + y) * (1/p)`. Either way, it is not possible since 1/p is not representable in binary floating point for p over 1. It must first be converted to the floating-point format, and that introduces a rounding error that will likely cause some results to be an ULP off.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Yes, that's what I meant. So, it seems that avoiding a division and the rounding error are bound together.

Answer (score 2):

I put some effort into optimizing my previous answer and ended up with this.

```
inline uint32_t digits_10(uint32_t x) {
  return 1u
      + (x >= 10u)
      + (x >= 100u)
      + (x >= 1000u)
      + (x >= 10000u)
      + (x >= 100000u)
      + (x >= 1000000u)
      + (x >= 10000000u)
      + (x >= 100000000u)
      + (x >= 1000000000u)
      ;
}

inline uint64_t pow_10(uint32_t exp) {
  uint64_t res = 1;
  while(exp--) {
    res *= 10u;
  }
  return res;
}

inline double fast_zip(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
  return x + static_cast<double>(y) / pow_10(digits_10(y));
}
```

Comment: Here is the benchmark compared to @3Dave implementation http://quick-bench.com/0KN46EiDISDW8DQKdxNnbVMOyB0

Comment: Tarek - while it's true that OP said that in a comment, it's not what OP asked and what most people answered. That means everybody else's answers can't be directly compared against yours. Can you please also provide an `int` solution for benchmarking? Obviously with `uint16_t` it's somewhat faster.

Comment: Updated to uint32_t to align with other answers. Let's see how fast is this. http://quick-bench.com/4Ur-hb9ArPzFiPIajgaJ8w-3T2Y

Answer (score 0):

Simple and very fast solution is converting both values `x` and `y` to string, then concatenate them, then casting the result into a floating number as following:

```
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>
std::string x_string = std::to_string(x);
std::string y_string = std::to_string(y);
std::cout << x_string +"."+ y_string ; // the result, cast it to float if needed
```

Comment: You probably mean `std::cout << x+"."+y`

Comment: @user3365922, yes.

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP didn't say they wanted to just print the value.

Comment: @einpoklum how is that?, plus the cout was for demonstrations only, he can do what ever he want with the resulted data, the important is the idea.

Comment: @einpoklum: Just out of curiosity: Are you downvoting all these answers?

Comment: @ArminMontigny: I downvoted the answers suggesting the use of strings.

Comment: @einpoklum why? i could use log and/or tons of mathematical methods, but why when there is a much easier way using strings?

Comment: @einpoklum: In the first comment to the questions, user harold asked, how to produce 1.01. That is indeed a good question. Without strings or character operations, this will be difficult to achieve. In your post, you did not answer the question at all. But I do not downvote it. Basically I do never downvote answers (except when they are flat wrong and misleading) and especially, if I can see some effort in there. But, hey, this is (still) a free world. Everybody can do what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(Answer based on the fact that OP has not indicated what they want to use the `float` for.)</sub>

The fastest (most efficient) way is to do it implicitly, but **not actually do anything** (after compiler optimizations).

That is, write a "pseudo-float" class, whose members are integers of x and y's types before and after the decimal point; and have operators for doing whatever it is you were going to do with the float: operator+, operator*, operator/, operator- and maybe even implementations of pow(), log2(), log10() and so on.

Unless what you were planning to do is literally save a 4-byte float somewhere for later use, it would almost certainly be faster if you had the next operand you need to work with then to really create a float from just x and y, already losing precision and wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
float int2Float(int integer,int decimal)
{
    float sign = integer/abs(integer);
    float tm = abs(integer), tm2 = abs(decimal);
    int base = decimal == 0 ? -1 : log10(decimal);
    tm2/=pow(10,base+1);
    return (tm+tm2)*sign;
}
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    cin >>x >>y;
    cout << int2Float(x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

version 2, try this out

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

float getPlaces(int x)
{
    unsigned char p=0;
    while(x!=0)
    {
        x/=10;
        p++;
    }
    float pow10[] = {1.0f,10.0f,100.0f,1000.0f,10000.0f,100000.0f};//don't need more
    return pow10[p];
}
float int2Float(int x,int y)
{
    if(y == 0) return x;
    float sign = x != 0 ? x/abs(x) : 1;
    float tm = abs(x), tm2 = abs(y);
    tm2/=getPlaces(y);
    return (tm+tm2)*sign;
}
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    cin >>x >>y;
    cout << int2Float(x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note `pow` and `log10` operate in floating point. Converting the results back to integers can inject some very unfortunate errors. Use with caution. There is often a faster, integer-only alternative that doesn't have these problems.

Comment: What if `decimal` is  0?

Comment: @einpoklum You're right, then we just have to add this line instead of using:
    int base =  log10(decimal);
We may use this:
    int base = decimal == 0 ? -1 : log10(decimal);
I'll update my post

Comment: Please use `x` and `y` for compatibility for other answers and to make my work simpler.

Comment: Version 2 produces incorrect results. Recheck it please. Also - don't have multiple versions of your solution, just one.

Comment: @einpoklum sorry about that I fixed it, if this is better then i might as will make it the only version

Comment: @aliberro Sorry, it's still slow :-(

Comment: For (1, 18), both versions return 1.1800000667572021484375, but 1.17999994754791259765625 is a closer representable value (in IEEE-754 binary32).

Comment: @aliberro: Perhaps GCC uses excess precision in some of the calculations. The C++ standard permits this, but it cannot be relied on. When `1.f + 18.f/100.f` is computed using IEEE-754 binary32 arithmetic, the result is 1.1800000667572021484375.

Answer (score 0):

```
double IntsToDbl(int ipart, int decpart)
{
    //The decimal part:
    double dp = (double) decpart;
    while (dp > 1)
    {
        dp /= 10;
    }

    //Joint boths parts
    return ipart + dp;
}
```

Comment: Dividing by 10, nine or ten times, is not fast.

Comment: @einpoklum Likely faster that 'log' funct or whatever method you use to figure out the number of digits. Well, perhaps a 32 if-tree depth is faster.

Comment: It's _much_ slower. 2.6x times slower on typical hardware. - see my benchmark answer.

Comment: Division is notoriously slow, while a good logarithm implementation is a largely polynomial evaluation combined with some bit manipulation.

Comment: For `(0, 10)`, this returns 1 but should return a value near .10.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, yeah. It should be `(dp >=1)`. But the code I posted is just a quick squeleton, not a full-debugged code. The OP's question is vague, so the answers too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that is simple to read and follow, you could try something like this:

```
float convertToDecimal(int x)
{
  float y = (float) x;
  while( y > 1 ){
    y = y / 10;
  }
  return y;
}

float convertToDecimal(int x, int y)
{
  return (float) x + convertToDecimal(y);
}
```

This simply reduces one integer to the first floating point less than 1 and adds it to the other one.

This does become a problem if you ever want to use a number like 1.0012 to be represented as 2 integers. But that isn't part of the question. To solve it, I would use a third integer representation to be the negative power of 10 for multiplying the second number. IE 1.0012 would be 1, 12, 4. This would then be coded as follows:

```
float convertToDecimal(int num, int e)
{
  return ((float) num) / pow(10, e);
}

float convertToDecimal(int x, int y, int e)
{
  return = (float) x + convertToDecimal(y, e);
}
```

It a little more concise with this answer, but it doesn't help to answer your question. It might help show a problem with using only 2 integers if you stick with that data model.