# I need to get a random number in the range from a to b with n decimal places

Tags: c++

I need a function that returns me a random number with n decimal places
Example:

```
int aleatorio(int li, int ls)
{
    return rand()%(ls+1-li)+li;
}
```

What i want is:

```
float new_random(int start, int final, int number_decimals)
{
    return // What should I write here?
}
```

if I would call this function 5 times like this::

```
new_random(0, 5, 4);
```

The exit would be:

```
0.2344
 
3.4356

2.8435

4.2435
```

I do not want to use this, because I need numbers of 4 exact decimal places since I will not use them to print, but you will have others:

```
cout << setprecision(4) << 4.24359675967 << endl; //I do not want this
```

Comment: Which language?

Comment: At this post it already answer this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560114/random-number-c-in-some-range

Comment: c++ and java plase, if I'm not mistaken rnd.nextDouble() is, very similar to rand(). @Jarod42

Comment: @PxnditxYR It's fairly common for C++ _questions_ to contain `rand()` but you rarely see C++ _answers_ containing it nowadays.

Comment: Plus `rand()` returns an `int`, or part of one anyway. `rand()` sucks. [Obligatory link to how bad and what you should do instead](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "C++ and Java please". You've only shown C++ code.

Comment: Do you want mixed Java and C++ code?

Comment: If you expect to get 20.3523 so that it is exactly equal to 20 + 3523/10000 it will never happen.

Comment: @WJS Wouldn't java's `java.math.BigDecimal` be able to do just that?

Comment: Either one is fine, I will write the code for the other language @ThomasMatthews

Answer (score 1):

> I need numbers of 4 exact decimal places

Then you cannot use finite precision binary floating point (i.e. `float`, `double` or `long double`) because those types cannot exactly represent all of the values with 4 decimal places.

A solution is to use arbitrary precision floating point, and another is to use fixed point. C++ standard doesn't provide arbitrary precision types nor fixed point types. Another approach is to give up the requirement of exactly representing those values and accept the almost exact values that are achievable with limited precision.

Comment: ... and here's an example to show what the lack of arbitrary precision in floating point types means for the random numbers: https://godbolt.org/z/553MPe

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a Java solution.  Multiply the start and finish by 1000, generating ints between the range and then divide the resultant number by 1000 as a double.

```
int start = 20;
int finish = 30;
int count = 10;

Random r = new Random();

r.ints(start * 1000, finish * 1000).filter(n -> n % 10 != 0)
        .limit(count).mapToDouble(n -> n / 1000.)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints something like this.

```
21.186
26.983
25.345
20.764
27.911
21.139
24.679
27.722
29.443
28.675
```

Or as a method supplying the starting number, ending number and precision.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(newRandom(start,finish,4));
}
    
static Random r = new Random();
public static Double newRandom(int start, int finish, int precision) {
        int f = (int)Math.pow(10,precision);
        return r.ints(start * f, finish * f).filter(n -> n % 10 != 0)
        .limit(1).mapToDouble(n -> n / (double)f).findFirst().getAsDouble();
}
```

Prints something like this.

```
28.4444
25.0259
29.5611
25.6445
25.4977
28.5124
28.9709
23.4835
27.9766
23.9438
```

Comment: Unless you use `java.math.BigDecimal` this won't be exact either if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Unless the denominator consists solely of powers of 2 and/or 5 no floating point fraction will be exact because they will all be repeating and rounded appropriately upon print out. but I don't really think that is what the OP intended. If they start comparing these values to others with no delta of accuracy they will be in for a rude awakening

Comment: I interpret "_I need numbers of 4 exact decimal places since I will not use them to print_" like OP indeed wants exactly 4 decimals.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an integer number N between *start* and *final* * 10^*number_decimals* and then return N / 10^*number_decimals*

Eg. *start* = 0, *final* = 5, *number_decimals* = 4 ==> N in [0 - 50000] ==> N/10000 in [0.0000 - 5.0000]

```
float new_random(int start, int final, int number_decimals) {
    return aleatorio(start, final*pow10(number_decimals))/number_decimals; 
}
```

You can define pow10 as:

```
int pow10(int p) {
  if (p == 0) return 1;
  else return 10 * pow10(p-1);
}
```

Comment: Better test that `pow10` function. Looks like the results will be downright comical if `p` isn't 0 or 1.

Comment: @user4581301 :-) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18581693/7582247) would be a better `pow10` option.

Comment: @user4581301 you're absolutely right! I changed the code to fix the problem. Thanks, also to Ted Lyngmo for suggesting better implementations (but that was not the purpose of my answer)

Comment: Of course I saw that possibility, but I separate integers and decimals because if I want a number from 0 to 5 there are 1/5 probabilities for the whole number, and 4 decimals 1/9999 probabilities @Stefano